# Laravel 5 - Redirect previous route to a new route

Tags: php, laravel

I have the following route group in my Laravel app.

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'home'], function() {
  Route::controllers([
    'contents'  => 'site\ContentController',
  ]);
});
```

Now I want to change the prefix to something else

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'user'], function() {
  Route::controllers([
    'contents'  => 'site\ContentController',
  ]);
});
```

How do I redirect the old "prefix" route to the new one so that any old URLs are correctly redirected?

Comment: By redirect, do you mean to redirect with a 301 code so that crawlers know the content has moved? Or do you just want the content to be accessible by both the `home` and `user` routes?

Comment: I was hoping it would be something like Route::group['prefix'=>'home'], function() { Redirect::to('a/user/')...... ?? (as in handle it directly in the routes.php?)

Comment: Apache is faster than handling this inside application (see response from Jeemusu).

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what the specific URLs are within /home/, so I'm going to assume you want any URLs to anything in /home/* to redirect to the same URL in /user/.

Because this is a permanent change, you want to be sure to do a 301 "permanent" redirect.

```
Route::any('home/{restOfURL}', function ($restOfURL) {
    return redirect("/user/$restOfURL", 301);
})->where('restOfURL', '.*');
```

By the way, that where() part at the end is needed to allow '/' in the path and to make it just get the whole thing in case you have URLs with more slashes (such as "/home/foo/bar").

Answer (score 0):

If you need to redirect with a **301 Moved Permanently** status code (to inform bots crawling your site that the content has permanently moved to a new url), then you could use a rewrite rule in your sites `.htaccess`.

`RewriteRule ^home/(.*)$ /user/$1 [R=301,NC,L]`